# Архитектура CMS на PHP

Tags: php, mvc, cms

Пишу CMS на PHP с использованием паттерна MVC.

Проблема заключается в том, что не знаю как удобнее организовать автозагрузку и расположение файлов контроллеров, моделей и т.д. Имею ввиду архитектурно, как написать, чтобы работало знаю.

Есть варианты:

- Использовать свой автозагрузчик
- Использовать загрузчик composer (у меня в любом случае будут некоторые пакеты из него использоваться)

По поводу физического расположения есть варианты:

- Сделать пакет для composer и хранить в папке vendor
- Хранить в папке App в корне сайта (или любой другой)

И третья проблема вытекающая из всего этого - как организовать неймспейсы.

Надеюсь я достаточно четко сформулировал проблему. Если нет, буду править с помощью уточняющих комментариев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать автозагрузчик композера. Нет смысла писать еще один такой же.

По поводу физического расположения - текущее приложение должно быть в корне проекта, сами файлы библиотеки - скачиваться через `packagist.org` в `/vendor`, при этом текущее приложение может тупо ограничиваться одним файлом `public/index.php`. Ябы целенаправленно делил систему на "библиотеку" и "текущее приложение", в которой файлы текущего приложения могут быть в произвольном неймспейсе и подключаться как плагины.

Неймспейсы должны быть организованы, как и всегда - `Vendor\Package\...`, например `Etki\SimpleApp\...`.

Последнее, что нужно сказать - вы, скорее всего, на самом деле не напишете целую CMS. Я тут с небольшим проектом "с нуля" бьюсь общим счетом уже неделю просто потому, что хочу организовать архитектуру целиком и полностью без изъянов.

Comment: Я уже больше года бьюсь над проектом, одна из прошлых версий как раз работает и доступна из интернета.

Стараюсь переписать движок, сделать его идеальным, насколько это возможно.

Т.е. можно не париться насчет неймспейсов, пихнуть все нужные классы в /App и раздать им неймспейсы вроде \Controllers\Index, скормя Composer папку App как место автозагрузки PSR? Если я правильно понял.

Comment: Если грубо, то да, а если не грубо - то вопрос, к чему эту контроллер принадлежит - к текущему приложению (т.е. расширению cms) или к системе в целом? От этого зависит, к какому пакету он принадлежит и, соответственно, к какому неймспейсу. Я очень не рекомендую использовать фиксированный неймспейс для приложения, результирующие классы теряют портабельность.

Comment: А что тогда делать с повторяющимися элементами вроде меню имеет ли смысл делать их отдельными модулями(или виджетами как в соседнем вопросе их называли, все же это немного рушит подход MVC) или просто перейти к HMVC и вызывать их отдельно? Из плюсов второго подхода вижу возможность перегружать такие элементы через Ajax.

Если я правильно понял предыдущий комментарий, то контроллер панели администрирования имеет смысл держать в пакете так как он относится к системе в целом?

Comment: "имеет ли смысл делать их отдельными виджетами или просто перейти к HMVC и вызывать их отдельно?" - это вопрос непосредственно к архитектору системы, т.е. к вам. Больше никто на этот вопрос не может ответить. Ajax-то конечно хорошо, но если смотреть глобальнее, то динамичные системы все-таки проще делать как SPA, где у бекэнда абсолютно иная архитектура. "Если я правильно понял предыдущий комментарий, то контроллер панели администрирования имеет смысл держать в пакете так как он относится к системе в целом" - да, только у системы должна быть возможность расширения.

Comment: Не совсем понял первый раз вижу аббревиатуру SPA. Вы имеете ввиду Single Page App?

Comment: да, когда все происходит на несколько более серьезном уровне, чем просто ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте готовый фреймворк. Выберите современный, там уже за вас всё придумали, останется только дописать нужный функционал. Я советую Yii2 (шаблон basic для начала), там уже и композер есть, и экстеншены и модули и генирация кода и всё что душе угодно, при этом всё разложено аккуратно по папочкам, есть документация (в том числе на русском), постоянно выходят обновления, сообщество ...

TL;DR: Не надо изобретать велосипед, ещё одна CMS тем более без поддержки сообществом - никому не нужна.

Comment: У пользователя могут быть разные причины для написания этой cms, вплоть до набития шишек на подводных камнях в целях благополучия впоследствие написанных проектов, поэтому не стоит ему однозначно советовать отказаться от затеи, хотя в целом с предубеждениями против этой идеи согласен.

Comment: Ну тут у нас есть "комментарии", этот вопрос можно обсудить. Судя по тому что автор уже год копается с этой проблемой - мне кажется шишек он уже набил, можно уже начинать дело делать. Не нравится использовать фреймворк - по крайней мере посмотреть как сделано там. В разработке большинства современных фреймворков/cms участвуют кучи народу, причём часто - далеко не самого глупого. Если цель опыт - вот он, в чистом, рафинированном виде.

Comment: У меня есть свои причины не пользоваться готовыми фреймворками.

А вот предыдущий комментарий был полезен насчет покопаться в коде фреймворков.

Comment: Это в любом случае только советы, рекомендации, а не ультимативные требования. Решать всё равно вам. Не хотите - не пользуйтесь, но люди реально сидели толпой и думали как сделать лучше. Годами полировали алгоритмы, пробовали, ошибались и т.д. чтобы вам не пришлось это всё повторять с нуля. Год того же Yii - открыт, лежит прямо на гитхабе, если требуется.